# "Did you come", or "did you coming" in continuous?

Tags: tense, exam-questions

I had an English exam days ago and a question was written like this:

> In what year did you ____ to the United States?
>
> A. come
>   B. coming

So I chose A, but the teacher insisted that it was B, because it was continuous. What do you think?

Comment: Where on earth did the "teacher" fail to learn English?

Comment: *To do* is only ever used with the bare infinitive of the verb (Did you eat?  I do run, they don't work etc.) so your teacher is completely incorrect if he or she insists that it's *coming*.

Comment: If the teacher insisted it was B, the teacher is a very bad teacher. Also, in what year is a bit awkward. What year did you come to the US? What weeks were you coming to school?

Comment: @Lambie - Or maybe even: _When did you come to the US?_

Answer (score 1):

It is **100%** come! 'Did you coming' sounds ridiculous... why?

Because we want the present participle of the verb *to come* (come) **not** the continuous.

Now if you are remembering the question incorrectly, it could have been option B as in the following example: 'In what year ***were*** you coming...'

Comment: Nah _In what year were you coming to the US?_ is not idiomatic either

Comment: Agreed that it's *come*, but "come" is not the present participle of "to come".  The present participle is the -ing form.

Comment: @stangdon you are right, I meant present infinitive>?

Comment: @mplungjan actually, yes it is... it's the past imperfect form.

Comment: Yes, I understand it is grammatically OK. but it sounds very wrong to ask this in the present - as if the coming to America was a continuous action - better served by "in what year were you travelling to America"

Comment: @Cloud - But there is no such thing as a "present infinitive".  I think you just mean "the infinitive".